# Access binding-Object and iterate over properties to access all my custom Buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, binding, member

Hellow there fellow humans,

I am currently facing Kotlin Syntax gaps...
My goal is to iterate over the GameFragmentBinding object and access all the buttons which are of type AreaView (my custom Button subclass) and I want to add the clicklistener as in below example in a for loop .... I found the option of using Kotlin reflection to access the binding objects attributes, but I am unclear on how to use the object in the loop to set the clicklistener on each button (something with the button as THIS object in the `clickTitle(this)`???)

Looking forward for your tips!

```
Set the onClickListener for the submitButton
    binding.area0.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area0) }
    binding.area1.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area1) }
    binding.area2.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area2) }
    binding.area3.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area3) }
    binding.area4.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area4) }
    binding.area5.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area5) }
    binding.area6.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area6) }
    binding.area7.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area7) }
    binding.area8.setOnClickListener { clickTitle(binding.area8) }

   Crazy...
   for (prop in FragmentGameBinding::class.memberProperties){
   Log.d("Props","${prop.name}")
   if (prop.name == AreaView::class.qualifiedName){
   Log.d("Props","$prop")
   }
   }
```

Currently pops out>

```
2020-12-04 13:39:39.578 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area0
2020-12-04 13:39:39.578 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area1
2020-12-04 13:39:39.578 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area2
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area3
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area4
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area5
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area6
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area7
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: area8
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: gameTable
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: mGame
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: playerText
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: restartButton
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: textView
2020-12-04 13:39:39.579 28977-28977/com.sweed.customfancontroller D/Props: mBindingComponent
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to generalize this rather than using reflection or iterating over `ViewGroup` children.

You need to utilize reflection to find all members properties of binding object and set the click listener:

```kotlin
binding::class.memberProperties.filter {
    it is AreaView 
}.forEach{
   it.setOnClickListener(::clickTitle)
}
```

Assigning click listener to children :

```kotlin
binding.parentOfAllChildren.filter { it is AreaView }.forEach{
   it.setOnClickListener(::clickTitle)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but 
```binding::class.memberProperties.filter {
            it is AreaView```
resolves to>
```Incompatible types: AreaView and KProperty1<out FragmentGameBinding, *>```

Comment: I'm sorry I provided incorrect type check there, you should resolve the type of the property and check it if it is your target type.